# TCustomAttribute - "Constant expression expected" compile error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Given the following code snippet:

```
type
  MyIntf = interface
    ['{C6184693-663E-419F-B2DA-4DA1A0E33417}']
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  InvisiblePropInterfaces = class(TCustomAttribute)
  private
    FGUIDS: array of TGUID;
  public
    constructor Create(const GUIDS: array of TGUID);
  end;

  [InvisiblePropInterfaces([MyIntf])]  // <-- Constant expression expected error
  TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, MyIntf)
    procedure Foo;
  end;
```

Why does the compiler think this is not a constant expression ?
But given that I use InvisiblePropInterfaces like this, the compiler is just happy?

```
...
var
  I: InvisiblePropInterfaces;
begin
  I:= InvisiblePropInterfaces.Create([MyIntf]);
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pertinent section of the [attributes documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Annotating_Types_and_Type_Members#Allowed_Parameters) is this:

> It is important to understand that the values passed to the attribute's constructor must be constant expressions. Because those values must be embedded directly into the resulting binary, it is impossible to pass an expression that requires run-time evaluation. This raises a few limitations to the information that can be passed to the attribute at compile time:
>
> - Only constant expressions are allowed, including sets, strings, and ordinal expressions.
> - out and var parameters cannot be used, because they require run-time evaluation of addresses of passed parameters.
> - Addr() intrinsic and @ operator cannot be used.
> - The TypeInfo() operator can be used to pass type information, because the RTTI block addresses are known at compile time.
> - Class references are allowed, because the metaclass addresses (as the case of TypeInfo()) are known at compile time.

The key point is that a [constant expression](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Constant_Expressions) is a technical Pascal term that is not the same thing as a constant. I suspect that this is the root of the confusion.

Since it is not possible to have a constant expression that can be passed to a `TGUID`, you are out of luck with your attribute. Indeed it is just as impossible to have a constant expression that can be passed to an open array parameter.

I suppose that you could use the string representation of the `GUID` to solve the conundrum but that will leave you with messy duplication and an inability to pass arrays of GUIDs.

Comment: it seems I am out of luck with my first real use of attributes. Well, then I have to change my design and just decorate my classes with another interface, something like: IInvisiblePropInterfaces = interface function GetGuids: array of TGuid

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation. TGUID is declared as a record type and there is no way to make a record constant expression.

Comment: not true. You can just call InvisiblePropInterfaces.Create([MyIntf]) without problems. It seems that in its attribute context it doesn't compile.

Comment: When you call it manually, it doesn't have to be a constant expression anymore.

Comment: @Rob, but is ([MyIntf]) not a constant expression ?

Comment: No, `([MyIntf])` is not a constant expression. That's because `MyIntf` is not a constant expression. It's a record constant, and typed constants are not true constants. When the compiler wants a constant expression, it needs a *true* constant.

Comment: Almost, @David. There can be floating-point true constants, but the documentation apparently requires ordinal numbers. Otherwise, it looks like true constants are a subset of constant expressions. I don't think class references or typeinfo are allowed in true constants — generally, anything that involves getting the address of a singleton. On the other hand, I've never tried.